# hacer desde BBDD un excel con python

Tags: mysql, python, excel

antes que nada menciono que no tengo mucha experiencia con python estoy aprendiendo el lenguaje y mi dificultad es la siguiente de un query en mysql necesito que todos esos datos de cada columna los pueda escribir en una columna de excel propiamente sin embargo el código que he hecho hasta ahorita me los manda de manera continua osea toda la linea desacomodada pido de su ayuda para realizarlo.

aquí mi código

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
import pymysql
from openpyxl import Workbook
db = pymysql.connect(host="localhost",    # tu host, usualmente localhost
                 user="root",         # tu usuario
                 passwd="",  # tu password
                 db="areas")        # el nombre de la base de datos

cur = db.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT * from areas")
wb = Workbook()
ruta = 'salida.xlsx'

hoja = wb.active
hoja.title = "Fecha-Valor"
fila = 1 #Fila donde empezamos
col_dato = 2 #Columna donde guardamos el dato asociados a cada fecha

#Diccionario de ejemplo
for row in cur.fetchall():
   datos = row[0]
    for dato in datos:
    hoja.cell(column=col_dato, row=fila, value=dato)
    fila+=1
wb.save(filename = ruta)
```

de antemano gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lestat, te cuento que no tengo instalado mysql, por lo que esta respuesta corresponde a un ejemplo mínimo general, pero que de todos modos responde a lo que preguntas.

la variable **resultado_select** corresponde a lo que estás recibiendo al ejecutar **cur.fetchall()**, que es por definición, una tupla de tuplas, es decir, una matriz.

Luego, dentro del ciclo, has de tener en cuenta que cada elemento de **resultado_select** es, a su vez, otra tupla, por lo que debes obtener los datos que necesites subindicando la posición del dato que te interese, por ejemplo, hoja.cell(column=1, row=fila, value=**registro[0]**)

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

resultado_select = (("01/04/2019","valor uno"),
         ("05/04/2019","valor dos"),
         ("24/04/2019","valor tres"))

wb = Workbook()
hoja = wb.active
hoja.title = "Fecha-Valor"

fila = 1
for registro in resultado_select:
  hoja.cell(column=1, row=fila, value=registro[0])
  hoja.cell(column=2, row=fila, value=registro[1])
  fila+=1

wb.save(filename = "salida.xlsx")
```

El archivo resultante tiene el siguiente aspecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]